Getting No static resource WEB-INF/views/login.jsp even I have this file located in my Springboot webapp directory
I'm trying to create an application that user can login and be redirect to home page(which display a successfull login information)
My project directory look like this click here for image of directory 
As you can see, under main directory there are webapp/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp, but when I run the application and visit http://localhost:8080/login in my browswer I get the following error on the page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Nov 01 19:46:23 EDT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource WEB-INF/views/login.jsp.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource WEB-INF/views/login.jsp.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)

I also have a Controller class which should direct me to login page and redirect me to the home page when successfully login
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    public LoginController(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, Model model) {
        User user = userDAO.findByEmail(email);

        if(user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)){
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/home";
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid email or password");
            return "login";
        }
    }
    
}


Anyone can help? Thanks
I have try to add a Web Config class under main/src/java/com.../config/WebConfig.java which should be configuring my jsp file
package com.example.takequiz.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}

but this does not fix the problem

When a Spring Boot project in Maven flavor is built as a JAR instead of as a WAR, then the src/main/webapp is completely ignored (for the simple reason because it's exclusively used by the WAR spec). The web resources need to go into src/main/resources/META-INF/resources instead (conform "web-fragment" rules in Servlet spec). See also the abovelinked duplicate, there are several answers pointing out that.
